# How does a chained export work in react without the components in between actually rendering the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-component, react-functional-component

I understood the point that chaining of components can be done by having functional component in every files and importing the components at every parent level.

eg A imports B imports C

Lets say we have these 3 files App.js, Home.js and HomeContainer.js

where App imports Home imports Homecontainer

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import HomeContainer from './containers/HomeContainer';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <HomeContainer/>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**HomeContainer.js**

```
import Home from "../components/Home";
function HomeContainer(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Home/>
        </div>
    )
}
export default HomeContainer
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';

function Home(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Home</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

Up until now everything was okay but lets say instead of creating a function component for HomeContainer I exported Home component directly, I see even then it is working.

**HomeContainer.js** becomes

```
import Home from "../components/Home";
export default Home
```

I want to know how exactly this is working, because APP.js is rendering the HomeContainer component but HomeContainer component is not rendering anything like `<Home/>` but still Home component gets rendered in the APP.js.

I expected App to render first functional component HomeContainer which in turn renders Home component. But even when we don't create a functional component and directly export it, its getting rendered in App.js as Home component when our HomeComponent is not even rendering it using the command `<Home/>`

How exactly export default in `HomeComponent.js` is rendering the component `Home`  in parent `App.js`

Comment: `HomeContainer` Doesn't use its import. Is that a typo? Did you mean to use `<h1><Home /></h1>`? Because right now, `Home` and `HomeContainer` have the same content, so it would be hard to tell what's actually rendering.

Comment: yup, edited code, is the question clear or do you want me to add more details?

Comment: "HomeContainer component is not rendering anything like <Home/>" According to your edit, `HomeContainer` is calling `<Home/>` which renders that component. So I'm not sure what your question really is.

Comment: can you check the second part after `Up until now` @AlexWayne

Comment: see now I am exporting home to App from homecontainer but I am not rendering it like `<Home/>` from the homecontainer, even then that component is getting rendered by just exporting it, when our App js actuallyy wants to render Homecontainer but homecontainer is not rendering anything

Comment: Seems to make more sense after the last edit. When importing a default export, you can call it whatever you want.

Comment: @AlexWayne why did you delete ur answer, I  couldn't read it

Comment: @ksav's was better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `export default`, it doesn't matter what name you give to the imported module.

You are just pointing an identifier to whatever the default export is at the specified path.

---

### Default export

In this example, it does not need to be `Home`, it can be `SomeOtherIdentifier` and it will still work.

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import SomeOtherIdentifier from './containers/HomeContainer';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SomeOtherIdentifier/>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**HomeContainer.js**

```
import Home from "../components/Home";
export default Home
```

---

### Named export

On the other hand, if you were to use a `named export`, you would need to import the module with the same name.

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import { HomeContainer } from './containers/HomeContainer';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <HomeContainer/>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**HomeContainer.js**

```
import Home from "../components/Home";
export { HomeContainer }
```

---

Or you could use the `as` keyword to alias the imported module to another name.

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import { HomeContainer as SomeOtherIdentifier } from './containers/HomeContainer';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SomeOtherIdentifier/>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**HomeContainer.js**

```
import Home from "../components/Home";
export { HomeContainer }
```

Comment: cool, this makes a lot of my understanding clear now

Answer (score 1):

The `HomeComponent.js` is rendering the `Home` because you told it to do so! You're importing and exporting `Home` in it.

Think of the second `HomeComponent.js` as a middleman. It imports and exports another component (module). It's a common thing in JS projects.

See these for complete details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export
https://javascript.info/import-export

Comment: but I am not rendering home like <Home/> in homecomponent then how does it know that it needs to export Home to the parent

Comment: So does that mean it mandatorily needs to be exported by default and we cannor just export it

Comment: See this https://javascript.info/import-export